# JS array.map() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have the following function

```js
function findNeedle(array) {
    array.forEach(element => {
        if(element === 'needle') {
            console.log('needle') // needle
            return 'needle'
        }
    });
}
const needle = findNeedle(['hay', 'junk', 'hay', 'hay', 'moreJunk', 'needle', 'randomJunk'])
console.log(needle)
```

I don't really understand why my function returns undefined. I tried using forEach and I still have the same issue. The strange thing is that the console.log statement before return 'needle' executes

Comment: Just add `return` before `array.forEach`.

Comment: @Rado `.forEach()` returns undefined, so this wont work

Comment: Do what Rado said, but also change `array.forEach` back to `array.map`

Comment: why not use `find()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this
Because it return the needle to forEach function not the findNeedle function

Have a good day and if any doubts comment

```
function findNeedle(array) {
var answer;
    array.forEach(element => {
        if(element === 'needle') {
            console.log('needle') // needle
            answer= 'needle'
        }
    });
return answer
}
const needle = findNeedle(['hay', 'junk', 'hay', 'hay', 'moreJunk', 'needle', 'randomJunk'])
console.log(needle) //undefined
```

Answer (score -2):

You must return the array inside your function, else it will result in `undefined`. Like so:

```
function findNeedle(array) {
    return array.forEach(element => {
        // ....
}
```

But you have some other errors in this code.

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, could this help you?

```
function findNeedle(arr) {
    return arr.map((element, index) => {
        if(element === 'needle') {
            return index;
        }
    });
}
let needle = findNeedle(['hay', 'junk', 'hay', 'hay', 'moreJunk', 'needle', 'randomJunk']);
console.log(needle)
```

Comment: `.forEach` will return `undefined` so this won't change much